# How do you superimpose two images using MagickWand?

Tags: imagemagick, raku

I was just looking at Raku's MagickWand interface to imagemagick:

https://modules.raku.org/dist/MagickWand

And I don't see any way to superimpose two images.  There's an
MagickWand.append-wands demonstrated in examples/01-hello.pl6
that tiles images, and I see there's a montage method in the code
(for creating moving gifs?), but I don't see anything like the Flatten
method I've used with perl's Image::Magick.

Comment: Likely the maintainer of the module hasn't added support for it in the main interface.  It appears that in `MagickWand/NativeCall/Image` there is a sub `MagickMergeImageLayers` that maybe can do it.

Comment: I apologize if this is an annoying distraction but I'm curious to know if you have tried using perl's Image::Magick in Raku. Code like `use Image::Magick:from<Perl5>; my $p = Image::Magick.new; my $p.Read("imagefile"); $p.Set(attribute => value, ...);` etc. I think it would be a nice contribution to our tribal knowledge if you could confirm it works, even if you're not interested in going that route for your own needs.

Comment: (1) Thanks, I saw that MagickMergeImageLayers right after I posted the question.  I've got some code working that uses it, which is the answer to this questionl.

Comment: (2) raiph: that looks like an interesting approach, and I might play with it some time, but it isn't likely to do what I want very reliably-- I was having trouble with the way the perl5's Image::Magick does flattening (it's a semi-broken feature) which is one reason I wondered what the state of the Raku interface is like.

Comment: @JosephBrenner Maybe the broken flattening of P5's Image::Magick is magically fixed when you use it in Raku? That would be one for the books! (I've no idea if that's ridiculous but I wanted to be able to write a comment saying thanks for considering the idea, and for getting code working with the Raku module and writing up your answer. So, thanks. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got some code working using MagickMergeImageLayers, I subclassed MagickWand and added a method to do it (following along with what was done in the append-wands method).

Here's the subclass module:

```
use MagickWand;

use NativeCall;
use MagickWand::NativeCall;
use MagickWand::NativeCall::DrawingWand;
use MagickWand::NativeCall::Image;
use MagickWand::NativeCall::Mogrify;
use MagickWand::NativeCall::PixelIterator;
use MagickWand::NativeCall::PixelWand;
use MagickWand::NativeCall::Property;
use MagickWand::NativeCall::Wand;
use MagickWand::NativeCall::WandView;
use MagickWand::NativeCall::Deprecated;
use MagickWand::Enums;

class MagickWand::Doomed is MagickWand {

    submethod flatten-wands(+@wands) returns MagickWand {
        die "List must be defined with at least two elements" unless @wands.defined && @wands.elems >= 2;
        my $temp-wand = NewMagickWand;  # this "wand" is a cpointer
        MagickSetLastIterator($temp-wand);

        for @wands -> $wand {
            MagickAddImage($temp-wand, $wand.handle);  
            MagickSetLastIterator($temp-wand);
        }

        MagickSetFirstIterator($temp-wand);
        # an integer expected as second argument but the value
        # doesn't seem to do anything
        my $cloned-wand = MagickMergeImageLayers( $temp-wand, 0 );   

        DestroyMagickWand( $temp-wand );
        return MagickWand.new( handle => $cloned-wand );
    }
}
```

Some sample script code that uses the above:

```
use MagickWand::Doomed;

my @images;  # stack of images to process ("wands", i.e. MagickWand objects)

my $bg = MagickWand::Doomed.new;
$bg.read( $input_image_file );
my ($w, $h) = ($bg.width, $bg.height);
$bg.label("conan_limits");
@images.push( $bg );

my    $overlay = MagickWand::Doomed.new;
$overlay.create( $w, $h, 'transparent' );  
$overlay.draw-line( 150, 120,  190, 70 );
$overlay.draw-line( 190, 70,   220, 120 );
$overlay.draw-line( 220, 120,  150, 120 );

$overlay.label("drawn");
@images.push( $overlay );

my $output_file = "$loc/flattened-output.png";
my $comparison = MagickWand::Doomed.flatten-wands( @images );
$comparison.write( $output_file );

# cleanup on exit
LEAVE {
  for @images -> $image {
    $image.cleanup   if $image.defined;  
  }
}
```